# What is different between cache disable and enable on magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1

What is different between cache disable and enable on magento-2?

If i disable magento cache then magento will boost fast or slow.

What do i do for magento-2 fast?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magento if all cache is disable then page will load very slow. But if all cache is enabled then page will be load fast. So if you will enable all cache then your website will load fast.

You can implement list of below points to optimize your Magento website.

- Optimize images
- Minify CSS
- Minify JavaScript
- Leverage browser caching
- Enable gzip compression
- Reduce HTTP Request
- Merge CSS
- Merge JavaScript

Also you can analyzing your website in below websites.

- https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed
- https://www.gtmetrix.com
- https://tools.pingdom.com

Comment: can you give technical explanation  why page will fast load if cache enable?

Comment: Of course the page loads faster with cache enabled, because it does not have to load an element twice,  they get stored and the next time you need them they get loaded directly from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

1. Magento 2 Cache Management

   Please refer this link

   - https://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-cache-management.html

Comment: thanks for response.already i have google.please give proper answer if you have

Comment: (1) php bin/magento cache:enable:- increase  performance, imporove speed etc

(2) php bin/magento cache:disable :- Disabling cache types is necessary while development, since it provides the ability to see the results of your improvements without flushing cache